# Cannot use Custom property of a label in data triggers

Tags: wpf, xaml, custom-controls, datatrigger, custom-properties

I am making a WPF application with custom TitleBar. It also has a Custom Button style. Though I made both of the custom controls perfectly but while creating a resize button that changes it's caption with the windows state problem occours. The XAML code of the custom control is...

```
<local:MaterialButton Grid.Column="7" BackStyle="{StaticResource StyleWhite}">
  <local:MaterialButton.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding WindowState, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" Value="Normal">
      <Setter Property="Caption" Value="&#xE922;" />
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding WindowState, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"  Value="Maximized">
      <Setter Property="Caption" Value="&#xE923;" />
    </DataTrigger>
  </local:MaterialButton.Triggers>
</local:MaterialButton>
```

and the code behind is ...

```
        public string Caption
    {   get { return (string)GetValue(CaptionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CaptionProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CaptionProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("Caption", typeof(string), typeof(MaterialButton));
```

Please help with this

Comment: Can you provide complete xaml?

Comment: check our output window to make sure there are now binding errors.. your DP looks fine.

Comment: What exactly is your issue? Please also post the code of the MaterialButton, the "StyleWhite" and any default style of the MaterialButton.

Answer (score 0):

I have already solved this problem.
The XAML is ......

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:TitleBar}">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:TitleBar}">
        <Grid Name="TitleBar" Height="60" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              Background="{Binding Background, FallbackValue=SteelBlue}">
          <Path Fill="#FF2A5478" Style="{Binding TitleBarStyle, FallbackValue='{StaticResource StyleDesign01}'}" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="200"/>
            <Grid Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top">
               <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Name="Icon" Stretch="Uniform" Height="auto" Width="auto" Margin="5"
                Source="{Binding Path=Icon, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Name="Title" Foreground="White" Margin="5,0,0,0" FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                           Text="{Binding Path=Title, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
               <local:FlatButton Grid.Column="8" x:Name="CloseButton" Caption="&#xE947;"
                                 Height="30" Width="45" 
                                 BackStyle="{StaticResource StyleRed}"/>
               <local:FlatButton Grid.Column="7" x:Name="ResizeButton" 
                                 Height="30" Width="45"
                                 BackStyle="{StaticResource StyleWhite}">
               <local:FlatButton.Style>
                  <Style TargetType="local:FlatButton">
                     <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding WindowState, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" Value="Normal">
                           <Setter Property="Caption" Value="&#xE922;" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding WindowState, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"  Value="Maximized">
                            <Setter Property="Caption" Value="&#xE923;" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                      </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                  </local:FlatButton.Style>
                </local:FlatButton>
                <local:FlatButton Grid.Column="6" x:Name="MinimizeBtton" Caption="&#xE921;"
                                  Height="30" Width="45"
                                  BackStyle="{StaticResource StyleWhite}"/>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </ControlTemplate>
       </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
 </Style>
```